# Retornar e atribuir para um textbox resultado de consulta

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como retornar o resultado de uma consulta e atribuir para um textbox em asp.net mvc ?

O "Tipo" é um Textbox de outra tela, como posso gravar ele e passa-lo
como parâmetro para a query ?

Esse método que eu criei o breakpoint não cai, pois já existe um método que retorna para essa view.

Tentei o seguinte até agora:

### Classe de acesso a dados:

```
public BoletoModel IRPJ(string Tipo)
        {
            StringBuilder qryIRPS = new StringBuilder();
            qryIRPS.Append("Select Descricao1 ");
            qryIRPS.Append("from TiposNfsApp where ");
            qryIRPS.Append(" Tipo = '" + Tipo + "'");
            DadosNfsApp objDados = new DadosNfsApp();
            BoletoModel bm = new BoletoModel();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objDados.RetornarDataSet(qryIRPS.ToString()).Tables[0];

            bm.IRPJ = dt.Rows[0]["Descricao1"].ToString().Trim();
            return bm;
        }
```

### Controller:

```
public ActionResult RetornarIRPJ(string Tipo)
{
        BoletoRepositorio br = new BoletoRepositorio();
        BoletoModel bm = new BoletoModel();

        bm.IRPJ = br.IRPJ(Tipo).ToString();

        return View("Detalhes");
}
```

### Método já existente que retorna para a View:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(string Fatura)
{
       var model = RetornarItemList(Fatura);

       return PartialView(model);
}
```

### View:

```
<label>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IRPJ) : 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IRPJ, new {@class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:60px"})
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens duas formas de o fazer.

Usar uma `Viewbag`:

```
bm.IRPJ = br.IRPJ(Tipo).ToString();
Viewbag.IRPJ = bm.IRPJ;
```

E na View:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtTitle", (string)ViewBag.IRPJ , new {@class = "form-control form-control-custom", style="width:60px"})
```

Ou então envias os dados do teu `model` a partir do controller:

```
return View("Detalhes", bm);
```

Comment: não funcionou .. :S

Comment: Então, que erro esta a dar? Ou que problema estás a ter?~

Comment: Tentei desse jeito que vc falou e retornou no textbox uma linha de código da view.

Comment: Fizeste do primeiro método então, certo? apaga o `(string)` na view

Comment: Dá pau, ele fala pra fazer um cast que foi no caso o que eu tirei e mesmo assim não funciona ..

Comment: Tenta me dar mais detalhes

Comment: Eu esqueci do "txtTitle", no caso coloquei com o nome do meu campo mas ainda assim, está pegando o nome da model.